# Access SQL all classes that a student is NOT enrolled in

Tags: sql, ms-access

Kind of a noob to SQL here. I'm trying to build registration forms for our department using data from an access database.  The idea is to print a sheet for each student that shows ALL the available courses with check marks next to the courses for which the student is already registered.  The relevant tables are in a classic many-to-many relationship

Students (StudentID, FamilyName, GivenName, etc.)

```
1, Bennett, Shane
2, Bradford, Alex
```

Courses (CourseID, CourseName, Term, Year)

```
1, Level 1 Math, Winter, 2013
2, Level 1 English, Winter, 2013
3, Level 1 Bio, Winter, 2013
```

CoursesTaken (StudentID, CourseID)

```
1, 1
1, 3
2, 2
2, 3
```

The table I want is:

Registration (FamilyName, GivenName, CourseName, Is Registered)

```
Bennett, Shane, Level 1 Math, True
Bennett, Shane, Level 1 English, False
Bennett, Shane, Level 1 Bio, True
Bradford, Alex, Level 1 Math, False
Bradford, Alex, Level 1 English, True
Bradford, Alex, Level 1 Bio, True
```

We have approximately 300 students per term and offer approximately 15 classes each term, so I'm looking for a resulting table that has 300x15 rows, that is, all 15 classes for each student.

For me, the easier way to do this is to simply find all the CoursesTaken for a given StudentID using a DAO recordset inside VBA, then use VBA to loop through the form and set report fields true or false.  But then (several hours ago) I thought probably there's a better way in SQL.  I looked at OUTER JOINS but seems as though the results aren't exactly what I'm looking for.  Am I way off track here?

Comment: This looks a bit too much as a student exercise to me... But in fact you have nearly given the answer in your header.

Comment: I realize this looks like a student exercise; I'm a teacher so I made it as bland and clear as possible. Our department is government-funded and we have a bunch of new reporting requirements this year. I'm just an employee with a little bit of MS-access experience now feeling a little bit over my head ....  I also realize that my header is wrong. I'm actually looking for a full list of classes that ALL students are both IN and NOT IN.  I'm sorry but the answer is not as obvious to me as it is to you.

Comment: It's weird for me too that a college night school department would need to rely on its own system for student registrations, but we need this system because the registrar is closed after 4pm and we get a lot of walk-ins. Also, for the government reporting, we need to keep track of every student that comes in our door, even if they completely drop out or never fully register...and we just can't get that info from the main college registrar's system.